# If 2 of 3 conditions are met (w/o || "OR")

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

Q&A

How can I check if two of three conditions are met without doing a TON of OR-statements in my conditional-statement.

i.e.

`if (((a==true)&&(b==true))||((b==true)&&(c==true))||((c==true)&&(a==true))) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional statements like (a==true) to return the value 1 or 0 in your if statement...

i.e.

`if (a==true) {` is the same as `if ((a==true)==1) {`

because all conditionals are in the form `if (1) { else if (0) {`

To shorten
 `if (((a==true)&&(b==true))||((b==true)&&(c==true))||((c==true)&&(a==true))) {`

assign each conditional `==` statement as a numeric value either one or zero, add all the conditionals up and check if the value is greater than 1 (meaning to or more of the conditional are met) because if a condition does not == true it returns zero if it does it returns 1 and adding them gives you a numeric value...

shortened form:

`if ((a==true)+(b==true)+(c==true)>1) {`

And you can get even shorter if you are using a language that handles BOOL the way obj-c handle's BOOL.

`if ((a)+(b)+(c)>1) {`